# Time span calculation for hours and minutes in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, duration

The final result should display the user the time span between the start hour and the end hour.(e.g. start work at 06:30 AM and finished at 18:30 PM, the result to display should be 12 hours).

Now, I have to `DateTime` parameters; fromTime and toTime
Each `DateTime` parameter have an hour in 24 hour format, and also might have a minutes value of 30 min.

What I willing to do is to get the time span between those `DateTime` parameters.
For the hours I used this method:

```
Public TimeSpan GetHourSpan(DateTime fromTime, DateTime toTime)
{
    TimeSpan fromH = TimeSpan.FromHours(fromTime.Hour);
       TimeSpan toH = TimeSpan.FromHours(toTime.Hour);
       TimeSpan hourTotalSpan = toH.Subtract(fromH);
    return hourTotalSpan;
}
```

This is great, my problem is to get the time span in minutes if there is, and finally add it to the `TimeSpan` object to display.

If both have 30 min time span in the above way will return 0, and than I have to start check every parameter if it have a value in the min property.

Isn't there an easy way to get time span for hours and min together?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
TimeSpan span = toTime - fromTime;
// Split into hours:minutes: span.Hours, span.Minutes
// Total span in hours: span.TotalHours
// Total span in minutes (hours * 60): span.TotalMinutes
```

Comment: thanks, didn't knew that subtraction of two DateTime objects will give an TimeSpan, and more than that, totalHours property return exactly  what i was needed to display

Answer (score 6):

If you deduct a `DateTime` from a `DateTime`, the result is a a `TimeSpan`. So you can simply take

```
TimeSpan result = toTime-fromTime;
int hours = result.Hours;
int minutes = result.Minutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan span = toTime - fromTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public double DurationinMins(DateTime startDt, DateTime endDt)
    {
        var ts = endDt.Subtract(startDt);
        return ts.TotalMinutes;
    }
```